# TFS: Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-foundation-server

When attempting to connect to TFS using Visual Studio 2013, I get the following error:

> Key not valid for use in specified state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the VisualStudio forums post below, the problem occurs after changing one's domain password.  Indeed, this was the case for me.  I resolved the issue by following the steps in the post:

[Resolving error ...Key not valid for use in specified state.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56f8a63d-7d8e-429a-bc5d-f549a9207d83/resolving-error-tf31001-cannot-connect-to-team-foundation-server-at-accountvisualstudiocom?forum=TFService)

> FIX:
>
> 1. Close all instances of Visual Studio 2013
> 2. Delete this folder in the registry (just “TokenStorage” – nothing else):
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\12.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage

[image]

Comment: Life saver. Had this issue after we updated the admin password on our teamcity build server.